# Kafka - changing log.cleanup.policy to existing topic

Tags: apache-kafka, data-compaction

I have a Kafka topic that receives many many messages. Many of them have the same key and I'm interested only in the latest messages. Looking around this topic seems perfect for the config `log.cleanup.policy=compact`.

Can I change the existing Kafka topic configuration adding/changing config `log.cleanup.policy=compact` or I have to create a new topic?

I tried to create a new topic with:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic compactedPricing \
    --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 \
    --config cleanup.policy=compact \
    --config min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.001 \
    --config segment.ms=5000 \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9094
```

but I received the following error:

`[2022-10-25 16:01:40,114] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Authorization failed.`

So, is necessary to have a peculiar authorization?

And, in any case, how can I do it?

Comment: So regarding your question, you can change the cleanup policy for existing topics. I suspect you should use `--alter` instead of `--create` though.

Your error usually indicates missing permissions. How is authorization configured on your cluster? Do you have SASL, SSL or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using --alter to change topic configs is no longer supported for newer versions:

> --alter                                  Alter the number of partitions and
> replica assignment. Update the
> configuration of an existing topic
> via --alter is no longer supported
> here (the kafka-configs CLI >supports altering topic configs with a --bootstrap-server option).

The only way I managed to change this config was deleting the topic and recreating it:

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --config cleanup.policy=compact --topic connect-offsets --bootstrap-server kafka-01:9092
```